# Call an internal JSON data set?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is there a way to embed and call an internal json data set using javascript.

Currently I am using an external json file and using get.JSON to call it, but is there a way to include the json data in the same file as the html and javascript and also call it instead of (or in addition to) using get.JSON

Comment: You can simply create a JavaScript file with the content `var data = [...];`, where `[...]` is your "JSON" data, and include that. Instead of JSON you now directly have an array or object.

Comment: You can declare a JSON literal anywhere you use Javascript.

Comment: Whats the Problem? Put your URL on get.JSON - Done.

Comment: If you mean the implemented parsing of `JSON`, you can get it here too: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/. Or just https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible

```
formData = {
    param1: "param1"
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "data.json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```